# Выборка статистических данных бд

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Вопрос может не совсем технический, а относящийся к проектированию. В базе данных есть таблица users и много таблиц статистики -например ranks, view_count, likes и т.д., где примерная схема структур -id, user_id(кто смотрел или ставил лайк) user_id2 (кому поставили лайк или кого смотрели). Вопрос, как  грамотно спроектировать таблицы , если юзеров и записей в таблице статистики очень много будет. Понятное дело , что путем count(), или sum() можно вытягивать по id юзера, но эти данные должны отображаться в листе превьюшек юзеров , как в соцсети (визульно фото, чуть ниже -рейтинг, кол-во просмотров, кол-лайков).Правильно ли так делать, что в общей таблице того же rank искать по id юзера и делать громозкие count() и sum() ?

Comment: если вы ведет речь о том, что вам нужно собрать статистику со всех этих таблиц и показать где-то  в одном месте, то для упрощения два пути. Не знаю, в чем там громоздкость у вас агрегатных функций, но можете убрать все это во вьюшку и писать запросы к ней. Второй вариант - дополнительная таблица сводной статистики периодически обновляемая. Про какике объемы данных у вас речь вообще?

Comment: от 7000 юзеров в базе, дальше будет еще больше.

Answer (score 0):

С ходу вижу 3 принципиальных подхода:

1. Классическая нормализованная база, подсчет sum/count на лету.
   Плюсы: быстрая вставка/изменение/удаление. Всегда актуальные данные
   Минусы: относительно медленное чтение
2. Денормализация (вынос подсчитанных sum/count в какую-либо таблицу) с пересчетом на триггерах
   Плюсы: Быстрое чтение, всегда актуальные данные
   Минусы: Медленная вставка/изменение/удаление
3. Денормализация с отложенным пересчетом
   Плюсы: Быстрое чтение, быстрая вставка/изменение/удаление
   Минусы: Данные не всегда актуальны

Выбор зависит от количества данных, количество одновременно подключенных пользователей (если и то и другое небольшое, то "медленно" будет измеряться долями секунды), и требованиям к актуальности данных.

Например, для соц-сетей с сотнями миллионов пользователей и миллиардами записей нет ничего страшного, если пользователь увидит лайк не сразу, а через час-другой.

Comment: Вот) Спасибо за ответ!!! Вот как раз это и хотел узнать -между пунктом 1. и пунктом 2. метимся , между данными на лету(с нормализацией)  или со сводной таблицей (периодически обновляемой)! Тут просто на будущее сложно угадать, нам и актуальность очень важна статистики, но и как бы потом при большой нагрузке скорость запроса может превратиться в ужас....тут товарищ предлагает триггеры вешать на update,insert как раз для заполнения таблицы сводной статистики,  говорит у них сводная таблица в транзакциях заполняется после insert в нормализованную, но как то....уже и не знаю...

Comment: и нашел кстати статью https://m.habr.com/ru/post/64524/ , там как раз человек про расчетные операции пишет, касаемо денормализации -как вариант...